# Can I fix this with the using of API Spotify in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, spotify

I have this error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

at this line:  `vc.mainPreviewURL = posts[indexPath!].previewURL`

HOW CAN I FIX THIS PLEASE?
This is all my code,thanks in advance ;)

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var posts = [post]()
    var names = [String]()
    var searchURL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Shawn+Mendes&type=track"
    var oAuthToken = "BQCvqHzNOHyHgUTKvw43PdXV4yZs9jHvdIPsn3XbXNE5Jbg0zwNrpfwh81VMeuK5LQeRel0djaJT1IyLa1T9YzQmDypC5LkMD5z_NDzeAWRcEvH4fMc_nn50X2R_i8a38AMrjfMS8qPNhGYoHjAe8sFvjBSwQOereRr2RrEbmXc8JMGq7-Aq-ttalp87DuCRVy8mt8wVt8Muenihus8hXrctT071x7he2j_eGHJSWp7WoA5fOyk9xhzkxU_p_3Hkab6x6rbYCM4SFX9WlDtb5h_jikfehT-15Mjol_PmnRYo9WPnaCLKTs3AOblDlNk"

    typealias JSONStandard = [String: AnyObject]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        callAlamo(url: searchURL,token: oAuthToken)
    }

    func callAlamo(url : String,token: String){

        Alamofire.request(searchURL, method: .get, parameters: ["q":"Shawn Mendes", "type":"track"], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer "+oAuthToken]).responseJSON { response in
            self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
            print(response)
        }
    }


    func parseData(JSONData:Data){
        do {
            var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
            print(readableJSON)
            if let tracks = readableJSON["tracks"] as? JSONStandard{
                if let items = tracks["items"] as? [JSONStandard] {
                    for i in 0..<items.count{
                        let item = items[i]
                        print(item)
                        let name = item["name"] as! String
                        let previewURL = item["preview_url"] as? String
                        if let album = item["album"] as? JSONStandard {
                            if let images = album["images"] as? [JSONStandard]{
                                let imageData = images [0]
                                let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageData["url"] as! String)
                                let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL!)
                                let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData as! Data)
                                posts.append(post.init(mainImage: mainImage! ,name: name,previewURL: previewURL))
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?){
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
        let vc = segue.destination as! AudioVC
        vc.image = posts[indexPath!].mainImage
        vc.mainSongTitle = posts[indexPath!].name
        vc.mainPreviewURL = posts[indexPath!].previewURL
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't force unwrap the value, unless you are 100% sure it will have a value. `indexPath` is nil, that is why you get the error. Where is your segue called from? Where is indexPath defined? Also, when working with table views, if you want to access the index of a row, use `indexPath.row` and not just `indexPath`.

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    } @DávidPásztor
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
        mainImageView.image = posts[indexPath.row].mainImage
        let mainLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        mainLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].name
        return cell!
    }

Comment: Please include that in your question formatted as code, it is unreadable like this in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3X** 
Change this line ...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?){
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
    let vc = segue.destination as! AudioVC
    vc.image = posts[indexPath.row].mainImage
    vc.mainSongTitle = posts[indexPath.row].name
    vc.mainPreviewURL = posts[indexPath.row].previewURL
 }
}
```

Comment: I have this error now: "Cannot subscript a value of type '[post]' with an index of type 'IndexPath'....what means?

Comment: @Raksha `indexPath` has type `IndexPath`, so it can't be used to index an array. You have to use `indexPath.row` You also don't need to force unwrap `indexPath`, since it is a non-optional value.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanx

Comment: @Luigis94 Will you please add posts object type array in AudioVC. and send data.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your segue manual and call it from inside your `didSelectRowAt` function.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegue",sender: indexPath.row)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?){
    if let segue.identifier == "yourSegue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! AudioVC
        let index = sender as! Int
        vc.image = posts[index].mainImage
        vc.mainSongTitle = posts[index].name
        vc.mainPreviewURL = posts[index].previewURL
    }
}
```